# Tensorflow unable to run strip_unused.pb (has no attribute '__path__')

Tags: tensorflow

Following the tutorial on TensorFlow for Poets (Android) (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/#0)

- Attempting to use Inception model instead of Mobilenet

Trying to strip DecodeJpeg Op from the retrained model using strip_unused.py, but encountered the following error.

Error:

```
/home/user/tensorflow/bin/python: Error while finding spec for 'tensorflow.python.tools.strip_unused.py' (AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.tools.strip_unused' has no attribute '__path__')
```

Command line:

```
python -m tensorflow.python.tools.strip_unused.py --input_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --output_graph=tf_files/stripped_graph.pb  --input_node_names="Mul"  --output_node_names="final_result" --input_binary=true
```

Machine:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Python 3.5.2
- TensorFlow 1.4.1

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Might be due to the typo mistake as file extension .py was specified. This seemed to work:

```
python -m tensorflow.python.tools.strip_unused --input_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --output_graph=tf_files/stripped_graph.pb  --input_node_names="Mul"  --output_node_names="final_result" --input_binary=true
```

Result: 997 ops in the final graph.